# Change or override javascript functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I am trying to override a couple of javascript functions. The javascript is loaded by the [Requestly extension](http://www.requestly.in) in chrome. I think all of the code is encapsulated inside a function, wrapped in ();

```
// start of the file
"use strict";
!function(Bt, Xt) {
    "object" == typeof module && "object" == typeof module.exports ? 
    module.exports = Bt.document ? Xt(Bt, !0) : function(Gt) {
        if (!Gt.document)
            throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
        return Xt(Gt)
    }
    : Xt(Bt)
}("undefined" == typeof window ? this : window, function(Bt, Xt) {
    function Gt(Cr, Pr) {
        var Ar = (Pr = Pr || kn).createElement("script");
        Ar.text = Cr,
        Pr.head.appendChild(Ar).parentNode.removeChild(Ar)
    } // all the functions are defined below here

    UI.writeLine = function(a, b, c, d=!0) {
        //display a line of text in the browser window
    }

    let UI_writeLine = UI.writeLine;
    UI.writeLine = function(x, y, z) {
        Network.send() // 1. change - comment out this line
        UI_writeLine.call(a, b, c, d, !1);
    }

    let writeText = new function() {
        if (var1 == 1 || var2 == 2) // 2. change - modify this if-test
    }

// end of file
}
);
```

My intention is to change a couple of lines in the loaded code, maybe by just loading an additional JavaScript file with requestly. I have tried to just define the two interesting functions in an additional JavaScript file that is being loaded, but it seems that only the original definitions are in use. I think the let keyword makes the functions private?

I can of course just make a copy of the original code loaded by requestly, and change the full blown code. But as mentioned, I only need to change a couple of lines and was thinking about overriding this either in an additional file or maybe in a user script. A user script though is probably a complicated and messy choice.

Although familiar with programming, I am not very familiar with javascript.

Comment: *I only need to change a couple of lines* which ones will make all the difference for the answer (if any) to be correct.

Comment: You need to show us where exactly and how these functions are used. What does "private" mean here?

Comment: I have spent some time editing and trying to clarify my original post. The script itself is very large, and minified with unreadable variable names. Hopefully I have included more relevant sections this time.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted it looks like you may be able to pass in a new function with the functions commented out or altered to meet your needs. The code below checks out in my editor (Webstorm 11 & Quokka). You could try to load this with requestly.

```
'use strict'
!function (Bt, Xt) {
  'object' === typeof module && 'object' === typeof module.exports ? module.exports = Bt.document ? Xt(Bt, !0) : function (Gt) {
      if (!Gt.document)
        throw new Error('jQuery requires a window with a document')
      return Xt(Gt)
    }
    : Xt(Bt)
}(myFunction())


function myFunction () {
  return 'undefined' === typeof window ? this : window, function (Bt, Xt) {
    function Gt (Cr, Pr) {
      let Ar = (Pr = Pr || kn).createElement('script')
      Ar.text = Cr
      Pr.head.appendChild(Ar).parentNode.removeChild(Ar)
    } // all the functions are defined below here

    UI.writeLine = function (a, b, c, d = !0) {

    }

    let UI_writeLine = UI.writeLine
    UI.writeLine = function (x, y, z) {
      //Network.send() // 1. change - comment out this line
      UI_writeLine.call(a, b, c, d, !1)
    }

    let writeText = function () {
      if (var1 === 'my value 1' || var2 === 'my value 2') { // 2. change - modify this if-test
        // Do what I need
      }
    }
    // end of file
  }

}
```

A little-known thing you can leverage in javascript is the fact that you can override expressive function like variables.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. If I create an additional file and load it with requestly, I just get an error on line 8: `: Xt(Bt) Uncaught TypeError: Xt is not a function`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Xqf.png Note, also the original JavaScript-file is loaded with requestly.

Answer (score 0):

In short your code follows this structure

```
function(windowArg, functionArg) {

}(window, function(a, b) {
  // Some Private functions here

  UI.writeLine = function() { ... } // First definition

  let UI_writeLine = UI.writeLine;  // Holds reference to above definition

  UI.writeLine = function(x, y, z) { // New definition for UI.writeLine
    Network.send() // 1. change - comment out this line
    UI_writeLine.call(a, b, c, d, !1);
  }

  let writeText = new function() { // Private function
    if (var1 == 1 || var2 == 2) 
  }
});
```

Now, look at the comments I have mentioned. With the help of an external script you can override the definition of UI.writeLine and comment the code you want.

So if you define one more script like this

```
(function() {
  UI.writeLine = function() {
    // Network.send()
    ... Other Code
  }
}());
```

And Insert it using [Requestly](http://www.requestly.in) after previous script. You should be able to see your code getting executed because you changed the reference of `UI.writeLine` to new function.

But `writeTest` is a private function within in the function, you can write modify that from an external script.

For such situations, I would suggest you modify original script and comment the code there. Use [Requestly Library](https://www.requestly.in/blog/2018/04/08/requestly-library-service-host-your-files/) to host your file, modify it there, add proper comment and copy the url and insert using Requestly. You can try out [Library feature here](http://app.requestly.in/library)

**Disclaimer: Requestly Founder here.**